# How to remove Facebook's notification count in browser's title bar?

Tags: facebook

To remove distractions from Facebook, I can use F.B. Purity or uBlock Origin with element picker to block individual element. But how can I remove the notification count appears in title bar of the browser?

[image]

To block an individual script, one need to open the [logger of uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/The-logger) and search for it. But when I do this with Facebook, I don't know which one should I choose. From my understanding, it's a kind of obfuscation of Facebook to prevent unwanted modifications.

There are tutorials on [making the title bar changing](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-display-update-notifications-in-the-browser-tab--cms-23458), but I can't find how to turn it off. However, this question may help: [How to disable the flashing title when someone messages me on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74830/63572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a userscript (using something like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)) and do something like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Title notification remover
// @namespace    https://zachsaucier.com/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Removes the notification count from the title of all webpages
// @author       Zach Saucier
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // The actual functionality to remove the notification in the page title
    var notificationCountRegex = new RegExp('^\\(\\d+\\)+');
    function removeTitleNotification() {
        if(notificationCountRegex.test(document.head.querySelector("title").innerText))
            document.head.querySelector("title").innerText = document.head.querySelector("title").innerText.split(')')[1];
    }
    removeTitleNotification();

    var observeDOM = (function() {
        var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver,
            eventListenerSupported = window.addEventListener;

        return function(obj, callback) {
            if(MutationObserver) {
                // Define a new observer
                var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
                    if(mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length )
                        callback();
                });
                // Have the observer observe foo for changes in children
                obs.observe(obj, {childList: true, subtree: true});
            }
            else if(eventListenerSupported ) {
                obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);
                obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
            }
        };
    })();

    // Observe a specific DOM element:
    observeDOM(document.head.querySelector("title"), function() { 
        removeTitleNotification();
    });
})();
```

This will remove the anything matching `(int)` at the start of a page's title and remove it on load and in any title changes on every webpage (provided your browser supports mutation observers).

I posted it on [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/30416-title-notification-remover) if you want to install it from there.

The DOM observer part was pulled from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14570614/2065702).

Comment: Works first time. Thanks Zach!

Answer (score 0):

From the picture I assume that you want to have `(9) Title` or `(99) Title` or `(99+)` as notification indicator.

Here is the clean code that I am using.

**Works in Vanilla JS, jQuery, ReactJS, AngularJS (not tested) and most probably any JavaScript framework or library**

```
filterDocumentTitle = () => document.title.replace(/^\((\d+|\d+\+)\)/gm, '').trim()
```

**Usage**

```
if(notification > 0) {
    document.title = `(${notification}) ${filterDocumentTitle()}`
} else {
    document.title = filterDocumentTitle()
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/notification-check',
  method: 'POST',
  success: function(notification) {
    if(notification > 0) {
        document.title = `(${notification}) ${filterDocumentTitle()}`
    } else {
        document.title = filterDocumentTitle()
    }
  }
});
```

**Axios**

```
axiso.post('/api/notification-check').then(({ data }) => {
  if(data.notification > 0) {
    document.title = `(${data.notification}) ${filterDocumentTitle()}`
  } else {
    document.title = filterDocumentTitle()
  }
})
```

The `filterDocumentTitle` function removes everything that matches the above examples as notification indicator.